# How to sort post by custom table value

Tags: wp-query

How can I sort my post by the maximum vote in custom table

I have table like this:( user_votes)

[image]

here post id 315 have votted two times so I just want to sort my posts by maximum vote.
I am only able to do sorting by only date as:

```
query_posts("&orderby=date&order=ASC"); 
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();
            $postData = array();
```

How to sort or modify query_posts based on user_votes table

Thanks

Comment: Do not use `query_posts` at all for custom queries. Rather use `WP_Query`. Did you had a look at the `orderby` parameters and meta query parameters in `WP_Query`?

Comment: You'll have to write completely custom SQL for JOIN and WHERE parts and bolt it on to the generated by WP queries. Not trivial...

Comment: @Rarst could you give me any demo in your answer, how to write... O_o

Comment: Did you get it working?